# Macro to find duplicates rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a macro to find duplicate rows in a spreadsheet. So far I have come up with this set of code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
    For Each cell2 In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells 'Loop through entire column A for each iteration in nested for loop
        If Cells(y, 1).Value = Cells(z, 1).Value Then 'Duplicate value found
            For icol = 1 To 19
                If Cells(y, icol).Value = Cells(z, icol).Value Then 'If cell value in current row matches, highlight red
                    Cells(z, icol).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            Next icol
        End If

        z = z + 1
    Next cell2
    y = y + 1 'Next cell
    z = y + 1 'Next cell (y+1)
Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I have approached this with nested foor loops. The macro is supposed to look for a duplicate value in column A. If found the macro then loops through that row to check if the entire row matches. Every matching cell in this row is then highlighted red. This seems to work fine in small scale when the number of rows isn't too big. However when applying this macro to a spreadsheet with 7000+ rows Excel freeze up and crashes. I suspect this has to do with the nested foor loops. Is there a faster and more practical approach to this?

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/03/09/how-to-highlight-duplicates-excel/

Comment: Thank you. However I'm wondering if there is a way to approach this using a macro.

Comment: Record Macro of adding Conditional Formatting .. ?

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional formatting instead of hard-coding the red cell fills.

```
Option Explicit

Sub dupeRed()
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(lr, lc))
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
              Formula1:="=AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1, $A2), A2=INDEX(A:A, MATCH($A2, $A:$A, 0)))"
            .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Jeeped! I'm getting a run-time error '5'. "Invalid procedure call or argument" Am I missing anything?

Comment: 1. What line does the error occur on? 2. Did you correct the worksheet name? 3. This code was tested and worked.

Comment: I corrected the worksheet name. The error occours at:

            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
              Formula1:="=AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1, $A2), A2=INDEX(A:A, MATCH($A2, $A:$A, 0)))"

Comment: 4. What regional language is your excel version?

Comment: 5. ... and does your system use a comma or a semi-colon for a list separator?

Comment: My regional language is Swedish (Sweden) and I use semi-colon as list separator

Comment: I changed it to US instead. Now it works like a charm! Thank you very much Jeeped!

Comment: How would I change the code if I want it to only highlight entire duplicate rows? For instance if a row contains 5 cells and only 3 of them is a duplicate it should leave that row blank.